# Adding an assets image URL field to an RSS feed

Tags: assets, rss

I am creating a RSS feed from a news channel and I have gotten it all working except for the news story image which is an assets field. I want to pass the url of the image so I can pull it in via feed me into another craft site. I have looked and I can't find any examples of this working anywhere. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just include the URL of the image in the feed so it can be picked up by Feed Me on another site, I believe you can use the `<media:thumbnail>` tag:

```
<item>
    <title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
    <link>{{ entry.url }}</link>
    ...
    <media:thumbnail url="{{ entry.myImageField.one().url }}" />
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks guys that got me sorted

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [template that Craft suggests](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/rss-and-atom-feeds).
Then you can add the image into the  tag.
In my case the assets field is named "titleImage". I have a transform defined as "gallery" to resize the image down to a sensible size. I'm not sure if you need to include the width/height/alt of the image but I do in case it's useful to the feed reader. I'm not sure if different readers have different specs. This works in the Mac app NetNewsWire.

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[
    {% set image = entry.titleImage[0] ?? null %}
    {% if image|length %}
        <img src="{{ image.url('gallery') }}" alt="{{ image.caption }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('gallery') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('gallery') }}">
    {% endif %}
    {{ entry.summary }}
    ]]>
</description>
```